# How to save data for the editable grid in Ext JS using store.sync?

Tags: extjs, store

I have a form with one of its fields as editable grid.

1. How to save the grid data once I click outside the grid.
2. Should the method `store.sync()` be used after `Events.AfterEdit()` or be saved on form submit only ?

**Code:**

```
store.sync({
    callback: function () {
        console.log('callback', arguments);
    },
    success: function () {
        console.log('success', arguments);
    },
    failure: function (batch, opt) {
        //code for failure
    }
});
```

Comment: My question is how to save the data of the editable grid which is inspired by [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930513/saving-edited-record-in-a-cell-editing-grid), do we have to just use store.sync() and the data will be saved according to api in the backend automatically or there is some other way of saving data.

Comment: store.sync will tell the configured proxy to sync all new/modified records inside the store. i do it that way.

Comment: devbnz can you show me the example of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we don't need store.sync() to save the data of a editable grid. We can simply do it by normal operations for model if we have correct json data coming to back end by using model.save() or similar operations. Below is an excerpt for setting data.

```
var rowIndex = myGrid.find('id', yourServerResponseData.id);
var rowRecord = myGridStore.getAt(rowIndex);
rowRecord.set(yourServerResponseData);
rowRecord.commit();
```